# Unable to moving a document larger than 40Mb to a Drop Off Library with SharePoint 2010 Workflow

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, document-library, drop-off-library

Using SharePoint 2013 (but 2010 workflow) I'm involved in building a system whereby a file is uploaded to a document library by a user.

Once the metadata is attached a workflow copies this document to another doc library in the same site collection, then deletes it from the initial library.

In the 2nd doc library another workflow kicks in which makes some calculations and sets values to the item, the final step of this workflow is to move to the Drop Off Library in the same site collection. From there, content organizer rules route the document to our chosen destination.

The problem we have is that if we try to upload a document more than 40mb the workflow fails in the 2nd library at the final stage of moving to the Drop Off Library. If the file is under 40mb it works perfectly.

No matter how big the file size, every step of our workflow works fine prior to moving to Drop Off Library, just fails to move when over 40mb.

We have done lots of digging and noted that SharePoint defaults upload size to 50mb, however, this has already been upped to 300mb and still fails.

The workflow error is not helpful (UnknownError) and we are unsure what the issue is.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what could be causing files over 40mb to fail to move to the Drop Off Library?

Comment: Could you use a Sharepoint 2013 to move the file? With the Rest API maybe.... I've also noticed this 40mb issue when using Web Services to move a file, and only Rest helped me to achieve it (in JavaScript)